# It's possible to use apache pdfbox with a multipart file on a servlet java app?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Im using pdfbox becuase it does not overload the memory handling huge pdf files, for example i have a 2gb pdf file, with almost 1k pages. for each page i need to do something, upload and storage in a server,etc (server that honestly i cant access)
My problem is that the application only works with file declared as string path ex: ("C:\file.pdf").

```
private void doWork(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception {

        if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req)) {
            resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Not multipart/form-data");
            return;
        }


ServletFileUpload upload = createFileUpload();
      
        List<FileItem> fileItems = null;
        File file  = parseRequest(req,upload);
        
          PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(file, MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());
          PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);


try {
             for( PDPage page : document.getPages() ){

                PdfDocumentHandler pdfDoc= new PdfDocumentHandler();
                
                fileItems.add((FileItem) page);
            
                
            
            pageCount = pdfDoc.savePdf(fileItems);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


protected File parseRequest(HttpServletRequest req, ServletFileUpload upload)throws IOException, FileUploadException {
        
        return (File) upload.parseRequest(req);
    
}
    
    private static ServletFileUpload createFileUpload() {
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(
                new DiskFileItemFactory(IN_MEMORY_FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD, new File(TMP_DIR)));
        upload.setSizeMax(MAX_UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE);
        return upload;
    }
```

And the javascript front end code is the next one:

```
<form
    action="../../index/AddPdf?parameters=<%=parameters%>&select=<%=idNode%>&save=<%=save%>&sesionInx=<%=sesionInx%>&esPDF=true&scanner=true"
    name="form1" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div id="divFileUpload"
        style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 326; border-right: #333399 1px solid; border-top: #333399 1px solid; border-left: #333399 1px solid; border-bottom: #333399 1px solid">
        <table id="tableFile" width="100%" align="center" cellspacing="0"
            cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="file" name="file0" id="file0" size="40"
                    maxlength="256"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="totFile" value="" size="3" readonly>
    &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="valExtension('tableFile')">
</form>


function valExtension(tableID) {
    var t = "";
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        var o = document.getElementById("file" + i);
        var f = o.value.toLowerCase();
        var t = f.substring(f.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        if (isWhitespace(t)) {
            alert("Select your file to upload");
            o.focus();
            return false;
        } else if (isNotValidExtension(t)) {
            alert("The file\"." + t + "\" is not a PDF");
            o.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    
    
    document.getElementById("form1").submit();
    
}

function isNotValidExtension(e) {
    var types = ["PDF", "pdf"];
    
    for (var j = 0; j < types.length; j++)
        if (e == types[j])
            return false;
    
    return true;
}

function isWhitespace(s) {
var whitespace = " \t\n\r";
if ((s == null) || (s.length == 0)) return true;
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
var c = s.charAt(i);
if (whitespace.indexOf(c) == -1) return false;
}
return true;
}
```

I already try the app without multipart request, i mean hardcoding the path on the file variable, and it worrks but i cant figure out how i can make it work with the multipart. I really made a huge internet research with no luck, so i came here to make my first question i really really need help

Comment: Can you explain what goes wrong when not hardcoding the path? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Theres no problem at all running it on that way, but i need to hardcode the file path, and thats not the way to do  it.